# Can I give up my degree?

Tags: united-kingdom, degree, rejection

I did a college degree in computer science abroad in England. I only chose this subject because my father did not want to pay for me studying sports. I did not like nor was I good at it. I only passed because my tutor said that I would be able to pass if I work on the theory part, and so I did.

I hate my degree. Can I give it up?

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554). Do you have any motivation to get rid of your degree other than hating it?

Comment: Seems like simply not telling people about any degrees you might not want to claim is often sufficient.

Comment: Potential employers consider *any* degree to be a measure of intelligence and determination.  You don't have to work in the computing field if you can find something that suits you better, but hang onto that degree and tell people about it when you apply for jobs..

Answer (score 6):

Usually, you cannot "give back" a degree you earned. But of course, you can look up the regulations of your college and you can also write a letter asking them to invalidate your results.

But as anger seems to cloud your mind, please wait until you calmed down and think about it again.

Comment: I think by "give up", @sawsaw means quit midway through the degree, rather than erase it from history post-completion.

Comment: @astronat He said he "passed", so I assume he/she finished his/her studies.